# Algorithm to prioritize matching sets within groups before matching sets between groups

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations, matching, combinatorics

I'm trying to set up a networking event similar to speed dating but everyone can meet everyone.  People pair up and ask each other questions for 5 minutes and then rotate.  I have multiple groups of people interested in networking (Meeting each other). Lets say for now I have group A and group B.  (Groups may be based on age, interest, industry, etc)  The groups are different sizes and there may not be enough time for everyone to meet everyone using this typical algorithm:

http://www.slideshare.net/MarkRodeffer/easy-speed-networking-method-2814054

So I need a way to prioritize who meets who.  The members of group A are mostly interested in meeting others from group A.  The members of group B are mostly interested in meeting others from group B.  IE:  The groups are mostly interested in networking within their own groups but are still somewhat interested in networking outside their groups.

The question is, what would be an efficient/easy algorithm for prioritizing the matching so that group A meets each other and group B meets each other before the groups start getting mixed?

Comment: given groups G(n); for example G(0) could be your group A and G(1) your group B - is their any function that can order for any group G(k) their likeness of the other Groups G(n), n != k ?

Comment: Paddy3118:  That sounds like it matches my question, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing some complication, but a member of a group would always prefer to meet a member of his own group before a member of the other group, can't you start off by just holding one round robin within each group, only pairing between groups once the smaller group is finished?

Comment: Yes you could, but that would only guarantee you'd meet one person from your own group, right?  The next rotation would be unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given your answer to my comment about there being a function that can order inter-group preference then I would split the people down the middle and call half "men" and half "women" then see the problem as a [stable marriage problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) the first time around, ordering a "man's" preference for all the "women", (and vice-versa), based on their respective groups and on whether they have been paired off before and how long ago they were paired off together.